# C# byte[] array auto filling itself with random values

Tags: c#, arrays, list, byte

I have absolutely no idea what's happening here.

I'm creating an encryption algorithm for educational purposes.

Here's the beginning of my code:

```
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] block, byte[] cipher_key)
    {
        List<byte[]> debug_states = new List<byte[]>();
        List<byte[,,]> debug_cubes = new List<byte[,,]>();
        List<byte[]> debug_keys = new List<byte[]>();

        byte[] extended_key = KeyScheduler.GetExtendedKey(cipher_key);
        byte[] state = new byte[512];
        byte[] key = new byte[512];
        byte[,,] state_cube = new byte[8, 8, 8];

        debug_states.Add(state);
        debug_cubes.Add(state_cube);
        debug_keys.Add(key);

        for (short a = 0; a < 512; a++)
        {
            state[a] = (byte)(block[a] ^ cipher_key[a]);
        }

        for (short r = 0; r < 32; r++)
        {
            short i = 0;

            debug_states.Add(state);
            debug_cubes.Add(state_cube);
            debug_keys.Add(key);

            for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {

                key[i] = (byte)extended_key[(r * 512) + i];
            }

            if (r == 2) { throw new Exception(); }
```

When I throw an exception to check the variables shortly thereafter, none of them make any sense.  For example, from the very first time I added the state to the list of debug_states, it should have been all zeroes, but instead Visual Studio said it was 180,155,126,217..... The same thing happens with the state cube also.  Weirder yet, the values can't be random since they're the same each time I run the program but I have absolutely no idea where they're coming from.  The extended_key does get the correct values but still doesn't work correctly, see the next paragraph.

Furthermore, every time in the future when I try to change one of those variables, they don't change!  Farther on down in my code there's a for loop that changes the state, state cube and key multiple times and logs them each time and yet in every debug entry they're always the same.

What the heck is happening???

Comment: You keep mentioning code that isn't in your example.  It needs to be.  In C#, elements of an array are initialized to `default(T)`, so I guarantee that they are 0 until your program changes them.

Comment: Well... they're not.  I edited the post to include everything up to where I stop it for debugging.

Comment: They are, you're just omitting some important detail.

Comment: Ok, so now that you posted more code, you're modifying `state`.  So there you go.  I'll explain why in an answer

Comment: I'm really not.  That's literally all the code in the class up to the breakpoint.  You can see plainly that the first entry in debug_states should be all zeroes since I logged it before touching it, but it isn't zeroes.  What else should I include?

Comment: Yes you are, you just need to understand the difference between reference types and value types.

Comment: Got it.  I was under the impression it was literally logging the current value but I guess not.

Comment: If you want to "freeze" the array in time you'll need to make a copy (`Array.Copy`).  You can also just step through your code with the debugger.  Look at your `debug_states` object before and after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are reference types.  When you add `state` to `debug_states` you are adding a *reference*.  Think of the variable itself as a pointer to a block of memory.  All this means any future modifications to `state` will be reflected *everywhere*, i.e., you will see them in `debug_states[0]`, as you have.

`state` (`debug_states[0]`) *was* full of 0's when you first added it.  Later, you did this:

```
// state (and, by extension, debug_states[0]) is all 0's
for (short a = 0; a < 512; a++)
{
    state[a] = (byte)(block[a] ^ cipher_key[a]);
}
// state (and, by extension, debug_states[0]) is filled with values
```

No longer full of 0's, and that mutation is reflected in *every* reference to your `state` array.

Comment: Oh.  Wow didn't know that.  Is there a way to log their current values and leave it?

Comment: Take a look at `Array.Copy()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx It will prove useful. It only makes shallow copies of the bytes but this is fine for value types